# Series: two varibles, how to eliminate the (product) higher order

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion

I have a function of $f(x,y)$, where $x,y$ are very small numbers. I want to series expand it to the $3$rd power. However I don't want the terms such that $x^2y^2$, $xy^3$ etc. because I would reckon this as $4$th power. How do I tell mathematica to do this.

As a concrete example, consider the following input:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
δE = 
  x^2 (Sqrt[1 + x^2] - 
      x) (2 - (Sqrt[1 + x^2] - x)/(Sqrt[1 + y^2] - y)) + 
   2/3 ((Sqrt[1 + y^2]^3 - y^3) - (Sqrt[1 + x^2]^3 - x^3)) - 
   y^2 (Sqrt[1 + y^2] - y);
Series[δE, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}] // Simplify
```

In the output, I need only the terms $y^3/3-yx^2+2x^3/3$ kept.

Comment: Try `// Normal // Simplify`

Comment: @Lou This won't eliminate the higher orders.

Comment: Well then, this should work: `Expand[Fold[(#1.{x, y} + #2) &, Take[CoefficientArrays[Normal[series], {x, y}], {4, 1, -1}]]]`.

Comment: Redefine `x -> x t`  and `y-> y t` and use `Series` with regard to `t` upto third order. After taking `Normal`, you can then replace `t -> 1` again.

Comment: Have a look [How to neglect higher power terms in a polynomial expression](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/how-to-neglect-higher-power-terms-in-a-polynomial-expression)

Comment: @Sungmin Conceptually this seems to work, when you apply this, you will find it make the problem much more complex.

Comment: Why is that? `\[Delta]E  /. {x -> x t, y -> y t}  // 
   Series[#, {t, 0, 3}] &  // Normal // ReplaceAll[#, t -> 1] &` which gives you the correct answer. (* 1/3 (2 x^3 - 3 x^2 y + y^3)`*)

Comment: @Sungmin sorry, it indeed worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bound to be a better way, but this will do it

```
Sum[
 UnitStep[3 - (n + m)] SeriesCoefficient[δE, {x, 0, n}, {y, 0, 
    m}] x^n y^m, {n, 0, 3}, {m, 0, 3}]
(* (2 x^3)/3 - x^2 y + y^3/3 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comment by @Sungmin. A very simple way to do this is following:

```
δEt = 
  Series[δE /. {x -> x t, y -> y t}, {t, 0, 3}] // Normal;
δEt /. {t -> 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
taylor = (vars - point).# &;
init := D[f[vars], {vars, j}] /. Thread[vars -> point];
taylorPolynom[m_] := Sum[1/j! Nest[taylor, init, j], {j, 0, m}]

vars = {x, y};
point = {0, 0};

f[vars_] = x^2 (Sqrt[1 + x^2] -x) (2 - (Sqrt[1 + x^2] - x)/(Sqrt[1 + y^2] - y)) + 2/3 ((Sqrt[1 + y^2]^3 - y^3) - (Sqrt[1 + x^2]^3 - x^3)) - 
   y^2 (Sqrt[1 + y^2] - y);

taylorPolynom[3] // Expand
(2 x^3)/3 - x^2 y + y^3/3
```